# Bug on android layout generated by DroidDraw?

Tags: android, layout

Can anyone see any bug from my layout? I use this as an activity layout but the application stopped. The XML is created using **DroidDraw**. The application is tested on Samsung GT-N7000, Android Version 4.0.4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_lihat_komoditas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lihat Komoditas"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget35"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget35"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/widget36"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget38"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pilih Kategori" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_kategori"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/widget37"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget40"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pilih Komoditi" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_komoditi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/widget42"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget44"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pilih Tipe" />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_tipe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

-

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**
I just clean and build the project (I'm using netbeans), and it works fine. Maybe the bug is on nbandroid. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Which exact issue do you experience?

Comment: show us the logcat logs...

Comment: @poitroae, I use this layout once and it works fine until I change spinner Id. I run the application from Netbeans but it just crashed at the beginning.

PROBLEM SOLVED! I just clean and build the project (I'm using netbeans), and it works fine. Maybe the bug is on nbandroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a blind guess: completely **clean and rebuild the project**(s). This astoundingly often helps solving issues like these (incompatible and missing ids, etc.)